# How to display in listview columns from different tables

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a table which has foreign key from another table with information; it's like: in table person I have column `country_id` from table `country` where I keep some countries; and I want to display information from different columns of table `person` in listviews and to display country name from table country not the `country_id` which is in table `person`. 
This is my code:

```
        nameview.Items.Clear();
        countryview.Items.Clear();
        emailview.Items.Clear();
        bankview.Items.Clear();
        cardnrview.Items.Clear();
        com.CommandText = "Select * from Account";
        dataSearch = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataSearch.HasRows)
        {
            while (dataSearch.Read())
            {
                nameview.Items.Add(dataSearch["NickName"].ToString());
                countryview.Items.Add(dataSearch["Country_ID"].ToString());
                emailview.Items.Add(dataSearch["Email"].ToString());
                bankview.Items.Add(dataSearch["BankAccount_ID"].ToString());
                cardnrview.Items.Add(dataSearch["Card_Number"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please type complete query in `com.CommandText` and fetch the keys accordingly.

Instead of this: `com.CommandText = "Select * from Account"`;

Try this:

```
com.CommandText = "Select a.bankAccountId as 'BankAccount_ID', a.cardNumber 
as 'Card_Number', p.nickName as 'NickName', c.countryName as 'Country_Name' 
from Account A inner join Person P on A.accountId = P.accountId
inner join country c on c.countryId = p.countryId";
```

Now you should be able to do this:

```
if (dataSearch.HasRows)
    {
        while (dataSearch.Read())
        {
            nameview.Items.Add(dataSearch["NickName"].ToString());
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
```